# React hooks Jest, Enzyme Testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-hooks

How to test react hooks..? Is there any way to test react functions inside the components?

I researched many. But I couldn't find how to test react state changes(useState) and functions inside the components. How to test them?

Comment: Could you link some of your research?

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the code you want to test to take a look at it?

Comment: You may not need to test hooks if you are using testing-library, you only need to test for the relevant UI changes unless maybe you are using custom hooks which may need to be mocked